# Can't build React/Next project - found page without a React Component as default export (context api file)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to build my Next.js project but it keeps giving me this error in the terminal:

```
Error: Build optimization failed: found page without a React Component as default export in 
pages/components/context/Context
```

That's the React context API file, there isn't supposed to be any default export there. Is this a bug or what?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You should move your `components` outside the `pages` folder. `pages/` should only be used for page components as [Next.js routing is based on its structure](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction).

> Next.js has a file-system based router built on the concept of pages.
>
> When a file is added to the pages directory it's automatically available as a route.

By default, Next.js assumes anything under the `pages` folder is a page component and will try to build each file as a page.

---

Even though the above is the default behaviour, you can configure your Next.js app to [include non-page files in the `pages` directory](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-page-extensions#including-non-page-files-in-the-pages-directory).

To do so, you can modify the `pageExtensions` entry in the `next.config.js` file as shown below. Then rename your page components to have a file extension that includes `.page` (`_document.page.js`, `_app.page.js`, `index.page.js`, etc).

```js
module.exports = {
    pageExtensions: ['page.tsx', 'page.ts', 'page.jsx', 'page.js']
}
```

With this configuration, Next.js will ignore any file that doesn't contain `.page` for the purpose of building pages/API routes and routing.

Comment: This is too bad

Comment: @MuhammedOzdogan There is a workaround if you do want to include non-page components inside the `pages` folder using [Custom Page Extensions](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-page-extensions#including-non-page-files-in-the-pages-directory). See [Is it possible to put test files under pages directory in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70832134/is-it-possible-to-put-test-files-under-pages-directory-in-next-js).

Comment: Thank you. Storing test files or state related stuff in another directory makes things harder to read and flow.

Comment: wow, i tried the solution you provided and it works

Comment: This is great! Next.js team here is allowing for customization of what is loaded in main "/pages". Thanks for this!

Comment: As it works great for the first time, for me it did redirect to 404 page locally.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had an empty file  `index.js`  in a folder. Using Nextjs Default Router

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.

If you comment out all other code but leave this NextJS won't get mad at you:

```
export default function Home1() {
  return <>{/* nothing */}</>;
}
```

I like to keep older index files and components locally and on github so this is a nice hack. I just copy all of the existing code add it to a new file and then add 1 to it for example:

`index1.js`

You can also leave a comment to kind of bring you and other devs up to speed as to why you did this for example:

```
//good for history of index implementation and associated syntax logic
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be not declared default export keyword in context component.
Try it as follow:

```
const  Context = ()=>{
  ...
}
export default Context
```