# NextJs build fails

Tags: build, next.js

I can run without problem `npm run dev` and the application works fine. But when I run `npm run build` I get the following error.

```
Build error occurred
Error: Build optimization failed: found pages without a React Component as default export in 
pages/category/[id]/getServerSideProps
pages/category/[id]/category
```

This is my folder structure:

[image]

index.ts:

```
import { CategoryPage } from './category';

export { getServerSideProps } from './getServerSideProps';
export default CategoryPage;
```

category.tsx:

```
import FinanceOptions from 'components/financeOptions';
import Head from 'next/head';
import React from 'react';
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';

interface CategoryPagePropsInterface {
    category: {
        id: number,
        name: string,
    }
}

export const CategoryPage = ({ category }: CategryPagePropsInterface): JSX.Element => (
  <div>
    <Head>
      <title>Category page</title>
      <meta name="description" content="Category page" />
      <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    </Head>

    <Container>
      <FinanceOptions category={category} />
    </Container>
  </div>
);
```

getServerSideProps:

```
import {requestCategoryById} from 'models/category/request';
import {NextPageContext} from 'next'

/**
 *
 * @param NextPageContext context
 */
export const getServerSideProps = async (context: NextPageContext) => {
    const {query: {handle}} = context;
    const { category } = await requestCategoryById(handle as string);
    return {props: {category}};
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Can't build React/Next project - found page without a React Component as default export (context api file)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65598867/1870780)? You should move both `category.tsx` and `getServerSideProps.ts` outside the `pages` folder.

Comment: Well yeah clearly that's what the error message said. I was kind of hopping there was a different solution than moving those files elsewhere. Thanks @juliomalves