# Vercel "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'list')" How to solve?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

```html
Error occurred prerendering page "/components/movie". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'list')
    at MovieCard (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/788.js:37:70)
    at d (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:33:498)
    at bb (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:36:16)
    at a.b.render (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:42:43)
    at a.b.read (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:41:83)
    at Object.exports.renderToString (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:52:138)
    at Object.renderPage (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:756:46)
    at Object.defaultGetInitialProps (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:369:51)
    at Function.getInitialProps (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/_document.js:31:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/utils.js:103:33)
```

On my machine the application is working correctly but when I deploy it to vercel it shows this error.

Below is my movie.js component which receives a list object through another component called movies.js.

**movie.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import {
  Button,
  CardText,
  CardSubtitle,
  CardGroup,
  Card,
  CardImg,
  CardBody,
  CardTitle,
  Container,
  Row,
  Col,
  UncontrolledCarousel,
} from 'reactstrap';
import Link from 'next/link';

const MovieCard = (data) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.item.list.map((m, i) => (
        <div key={i} item={m}>
          <CardGroup>
            <Card>
              <CardImg
                alt='Card image cap'
                src={m.urlToImage}
                top
                width='100px'
                height='200px'
              />
              <CardBody>
                <Link href={m.url} target='_blank'>
                  <CardTitle tag='h5' alt={m.title}>
                    {m.title}
                  </CardTitle>
                </Link>

                <CardText alt={m.description}>{m.description}</CardText>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          </CardGroup>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MovieCard;
```

Below is the movies.js component

**movies.js**

```
import {
  Button,
  CardText,
  CardSubtitle,
  CardGroup,
  Card,
  CardImg,
  CardBody,
  CardTitle,
  Container,
  Row,
  Col,
  UncontrolledCarousel,
} from 'reactstrap';
import React from 'react';

import Movie from './movie';

function Movies(list) {
  {
    console.log(list);
  }

  const dataResult = Object.entries(list).map(([key, value]) => ({
    [key]: value,
  }));

  console.log(dataResult);

  let cards = <h3>Loading...</h3>;

  if (dataResult != null) {
    cards = dataResult.map((m, i) => <Movie key={i} item={m} />);
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <Card>{cards}</Card>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Movies;
```

This is the Search Component where I request the data in the API

**search.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import {
  Button,
  CardText,
  CardSubtitle,
  CardGroup,
  Card,
  CardImg,
  CardBody,
  CardTitle,
  Container,
  Row,
  Col,
  UncontrolledCarousel,
} from 'reactstrap';

import Movies from './movies';

class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    movies: null,
    loading: false,
    value: '',
  };

  //Request the data
  search = async (val) => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    const articles = await axios.get(
      `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?q=${val}&country=br&sortBy=popularity&apiKey=MYAPIKEYHERE`
    );
    const news = articles;
    const movies = news.data.articles;
    console.log(movies);

    this.setState({ movies, loading: false });
  };

  //Handle with input
  onChangeHandler = async (e) => {
    this.search(e.target.value);
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  };

  get renderMovies() {
    let movies = <h1>Erro</h1>;
    if (this.state.movies) {
      movies = <Movies list={this.state.movies} />;
    }

    return movies;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Container>
          <input
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={(e) => this.onChangeHandler(e)}
            placeholder='Type something to search'
          />
          {this.renderMovies}
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```

Here is the console.log's that I have
[console.log's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWDJZ.png)

Could someone help me understand what's going on or suggest improvements to the code so that I can implement it in vercel

Comment: I think `item` is undefined in `MovieCard`, maybe you can print the item object and check when vercel compiles

Comment: Can you post the result of the `console.log(list)` in `Movies`?

Comment: Thanks for the brief reply. I edited the question and added an image with console log

Comment: You should only have page components inside the `pages` folder. Move the `components` folder (and its contents) outside the `pages` folder. See [Can't build React/Next project - found page without a React Component as default export (context api file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65598753/cant-build-react-next-project-found-page-without-a-react-component-as-default).