# Issues while building the Next js website

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I'm working on a nextjs webapp, it's a static website built with Chakra UI. Everything was working quite good till now but suddenly my productions stopped building. It is showing `building` forever. I'm deploying it on the Vercel but the same issue is arising there as well.
My previous deploymnt is live at https://siws.vercel.app and it's working fine but I'm not able to push another deployment due to this issue. And I don't even know the root cause of this.
I even tried deleting the `./next` folder and building again but the facing the same issue.

Here is some information that maybe relevant:

`Node JS version: 19.1.0`

And here is my `package.json` file:

```
  "name": "slayitwithskin",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.4.1",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@splidejs/react-splide": "^0.7.12",
    "eslint": "8.27.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.0.3",
    "framer-motion": "^7.6.6",
    "next": "13.0.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-rainbow-components": "^1.31.0",
    "sass": "^1.56.1"
  }
}
```

Any sort of help is really appreciated.

Comment: Do you use yarn or npm?

Comment: You may get idea from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73348098/next-js-build-hangs-forever, and/or try remove node_module and use yarn instead of npm if you use

Comment: try node_version 16. node 19 does not even start some of my project in dev

Answer (score 0):

I checked my package.json file, I was using react-rainbow-components which was the root cause of this issue. I completely removed and the app is now building quickly.