# Next JS SSG Page shows "found page without a React Component as default export" while deploying in vercel

Tags: next.js, deployment, vercel, static-site-generation, nextjs-dynamic-routing

Just to mention that the answers in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65598753/cant-build-react-next-project-found-page-without-a-react-component-as-default) did not work for me.

So I have a page which used Static Site Generation(SSG) and no matter how i export it, while deploying in vercel the error always shows "found page without a React Component as default export".

This is my whole file:

File name : [productId].js

```
import Head from "next/head";
import React from "react";
import ProductDetails from "../../components/Product/ProductDetails/ProductDetails";

export default function index({ product }) {
  return (
    <>
      {/* <Head>

    </Head> */}
      <ProductDetails product={product} />
    </>
  );
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const res = await fetch(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API}/api/v1/user/products?page=${"all"}`,
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }
  );

  const data = await res.json();
  const paths = data.data.map((product) => {
    return {
      params: { productId: product._id.toString() },
    };
  });

  console.log("paths", paths);

  return {
    paths: paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}

export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const { params } = context;
  console.log("params", params);
  const { productId } = params;
  const res = await fetch(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API}/api/v1/user/products/${productId}`,
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }
  );

  const data = await res.json();
  if (data.status) {
    return {
      props: {
        product: data.data,
      },
    };
  }
};
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here. Becuase I have used this same way of exporting which is "export default function index" in other files and they don't seem to have a problem but only in this file I am having this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't build React/Next project - found page without a React Component as default export (context api file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65598753/cant-build-react-next-project-found-page-without-a-react-component-as-default)

Comment: Nope. My Component is outside the pages folder as you can see from the code. I am just importing the component from the components folder in this file which is inside the pages folder.